# Tablesorter sorting arrows are unable to use

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, tablesorter

I'm new to jquery and php programming.
Now I think it is stupid question and so many question about this here but nothing works. I have gone through these issue for nearly 4 hours already, I feel desperate to fix this.

[image]

As you can see, the table is looking ok. But... the arrows are not working.
Once clicked, it does nothing to me which I don't know what's wrong with it.

These are my codes so far. (I will skipped major of table codes to reduce the length of this post)

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.tablesorter/docs/css/jq.css?4005963428"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.tablesorter/themes/green/style.css?4005963428"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css?4005963428"/>


<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter/jquery.metadata.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script> 

</head>

<br><br>

<table id='myTable'  class='tablesorter'  style="width:100%" >
<?php  echo "<thead>";
?>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Lastname</th>   

<?php 

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

while ($rowss = mysql_fetch_array($result3, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    ?>
<th><?php echo $rowss['Skill_Name']  ?> Score</th>

<?php
}

}
?>

<th>Overall Score</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th colspan="3">View Information</th>

</tr>
<?php  echo "</thead>";
?>

<?php  echo "<tbody>";

while ($rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($result4, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
?> 
//table td elements in loop
<?php
}

echo "</tbody>";
?>   
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
// sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]]
});
</script>
```

I really have no idea about this, please help.

Cheers, GzNero

Comment: Is that your full code? where is the sql query

Comment: @Devs nope sql query is skipped, it is too long, does is essential to be included for finding the issue?

Comment: upload the above content somewhere in online editor and share the link.

Comment: @Devs alright here it is, https://jsfiddle.net/1jcLzyh5/

Comment: Your fiddle is incorrect. Remove all php code and use html with any content for example. Add external links to the `External resources` in the left sidebar. Add only js code, without `<script>` tag, to Javascript window. Add only CSS code without `<style>` tag. Make sure that everything displayed correctly in Result window.

Comment: Anyway, The problem is solved by using Tablesorter-master. Thanks for coming to help. Appreciate it !!!